# How can I parse a JSON Array of objects to a list of VB.NET objects?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I installed JSON.Net through NuGet and now I want to parse a json array with objects to a list of objects in VB.NET. I have no idea where to begin.

My JSON array:

```
[
  {
    "servername": "US - New Jersey",
    "ovpnlocation": "servers/newjersey.ovpn"
  },
  {
    "servername": "The Netherlands",
    "ovpnlocation": "servers/nl.ovpn"
  },
  {
    "servername": "Belgium",
    "ovpnlocation": "servers/belgium.ovpn"
  }
]
```

I have a list of objects that I want to fill:

```
Dim ServerList As New List(Of ServerLocation)
```

And my ServerLocation class contains this:

```
Public Property ServerName As String
Public Property OVPNLocation As String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSON.Net something like this should work, json being a string holding the JSON you listed above:

```
Dim ServerList As List(Of ServerLocation) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ServerLocation))(json)
```

Comment: Combined this with "<JsonProperty("servername")>" & "<JsonProperty("ovpnlocation")>" in my class and it works flawlessly. Thank you!